# Change Image/Class On Click with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm currently practicing JQuery for my Javascript class. I've made the progress of a sloth but it feels good getting something to work. (Login form to slide down and change plus to minus) My problem seems to be with changing the minus class back to plus and not freaking out the form like it does right now. Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code? excuse the complete noob.

```js
//Fading in Advertisent
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ad").animate({
    top: '100px',

  });

  //Closing The Advertisement
  $("#adbtn").click(function() {
    $("#ad").fadeOut(5000);
  });

  $(".plus").click(function() {
    $("form").slideToggle(500); // half second duration
    $(".plus").removeClass("plus").addClass("minus");
  }); // end function

}); // end function

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ad").animate({
    top: '100px',

  });

  //Closing The Advertisement
  $("#adbtn").click(function() {
    $("#ad").fadeOut(5000);
  });

  $(".plus").click(function() {
    $("form").slideToggle(500); // half second duration
    $(".plus").removeClass("plus").addClass("minus");
  }); // end function

  $(".minus").click(function() {
    $("form").slideUp(500); // half second duration
    $(".minus").removeClass("minus").toggleClass("plus");
  }); // end function

}); // end function
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}
a {
  color: blue;
}
#welcome p strong {
  color: navy;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
#welcome p:first-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
section {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
/* main container */

#main {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e0e0ff;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* form container */

#loginDiv {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 650px;
  top: 6px;
  z-index: 100;
  border: 1px solid navy;
}
/* paragraph that shows the text "Login" which is clicked on to display/remove the form */

#login {
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 5px 0 2px 30px;
}
#login:hover {
  background-color: rgb(110, 138, 195);
}
/*  plus sign icon for login form */

.plus {
  background: url(img_open.png) no-repeat 8px 7px;
  background-color: rgb(110, 138, 195);
}
/* minus sign icon for login form */

.minus {
  background: url(img_close.png) no-repeat 8px 7px;
}
/*form is hidden when the page loads */

#loginDiv form {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
#loginDiv label {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}
#loginDiv input {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 1px solid navy;
}
#loginDiv input:focus {
  background-color: rgb(110, 138, 195);
  border: 2px solid navy;
}
#loginDiv input[type=button] {
  width: 100px;
}
footer {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
/* ad is not shown when the page loads  */

#ad {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 330px;
  top: -500px;
  /* you can change this inbitially for viewing purposes only but be sure to set it back */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url(ad.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
/* close button on ad */

#adbtn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- main container -->
<div id="main">
  <section id="loginDiv">
    <!-- when this is clicked on the below form should be displayed and plus sign should change to minus sign-->
    <p id="login" class="plus">Login</p>
    <form>
      <p>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="pw">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="pw" id="pw">
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="button" value="Submit">
      </p>

      <!-- placeholder for response if form data is correct/incorrect -->
      <p id="error"></p>
    </form>
  </section>
  <section id="welcome">
    <h1>Welcome to the Local jQuery User Group Website</h1>
    <p> <strong>Click the login button at the top of the page to login. To become a member please <a href="#">Register</a></strong> 
    </p>
    <h2>About this page layout:</h2>
    <p>The main container (parent) has 'relative' positioning so that the 'login' container can be absolutley positioned with respect to that main container. Otherwise, it would default to being absolutley positioned with respect to the window.</p>
    <p>In order for the login panel to be placed on top of the page we need to use absolute positioning, otherwise, it would move the rest of the content down as done in the FAQ assignment. Technically, absolute positioning takes that element out of the
      normal flow of the document, so that it is on top of the page. The 'ad' is also absolutely positioned to the same main container.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>This week's agenda:</h2>
    <p>There will be a live meeting this Tuesday evening from 7:00pm to 8:00pm PST using our WebEx Conferencing Software. It will be recorded! Please note that the code samples will be available on our GitHub repository.</p>
  </section>
  <footer>Copyright &copy; Local jQuery User Group</footer>

  <!--  ad which is absolutely positioned -500px from the top so you do not see it when page loads-->
  <div id="ad">
    <div id="adbtn">X</div>
  </div>

  <!-- end main container -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **toggleClass** instead of **removeClass** and **addClass**. Also, you should change the .plus selector in the handle function to refer to the element (this).

```
$(".plus").click(function(){
      $("form").slideToggle(500);  // half second duration
      $(this).toggleClass("plus").toggleClass("minus");
}); // end function
```

Comment: $(this).toggleClass("plus").toggleClass("minus"); 

"this" is referring to this specific element of plus? how else could $(this). be used?

Comment: In this kind of event handler definition, the this keyword refers to the element to which the handler refers. This meaning that inside the function sent to the click(), this refers to the specific .plus element even if it comes to lose the plus class. So, $(this) is the jQuery approach to access the DOM element of this.

If we used the $('.plus') reference it wouldn't work when the element would be in the 'minus state', thus breaking functionality.

The keyword this works diferently depending on the type of call it's being made, though.

Comment: Could you also help me with a step in the right direction as far as writing some jquery to validate the login form before submitting. All there needs to be in the fields is some type of writing. If submit is pushed without entering fields then error warnings should show up

Comment: There are  different ways to accomplish that and also there are plugins for client side validation: https://jqueryvalidation.org/

One way is creating a function on the button click where you check if the field values are different than "". If this is true submit the form through javascript.

In client side validation always not trust the information that goes to server to be valid, since the user can always bypass these processes in the browser. 

This is a totally different issue, so if you still have difficulties you should open a new question after checking the existing ones.

Comment: Im still tring to figure it out !!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338667/beginner-trying-to-learn-about-validating-fields-before-submit-in-javascript/37339180?noredirect=1#comment62195778_37339180